# How do I configure a systemd service to execute simple /bin/echo "Hello world" command to show the output on the console?

Tags: kernel, systemd, kvm

I am trying to boot up a vm with qemu-system-ppc64(similar to lkvm). I am using the following command:

> `qemu-system-ppc64 --enable-kvm -vga none -nographic -nodefaults -chardev stdio,id=id1 -device spapr-vty,chardev=id1 -machine type=pseries-2.2,usb=off -smp 1 -m 128 -kernel vmlinux -fsdev local,id=root,path=.,security_model=none -fsdev local,id=containerfs,path=opt/stage2/hello/rootfs/,security_model=none -device virtio-9p-pci,fsdev=root,mount_tag=/dev/root -device virtio-9p-pci,fsdev=containerfs,mount_tag=/dev/basefs -append 'root=/dev/root rootfstype=9p rootflags=trans=virtio,version=9p2000.L  init=lib/systemd/systemd systemd.log_level=debug systemd.log_target=console '`

I want to show a simple "hello world" to the console. So I have written the following service file called hello.service in lib/systemd/system:

```
[Service]
Restart=no
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/echo "hello world"
User=0 
Group=0
StandardOutput=journal+console
StandardError=journal+console
SyslogIdentifier=hello

[Unit]
Description= Application "Hello"
DefaultDependencies=false
OnFailure=reaper.service
Wants=exit-watcher.service
Requires=base-mount.service
After=base-mount.service
```

But when I start the vm, i can't see the output "hello world" on the screen. Can you please help on how to bring the output on console?

Comment: Have you tried redirecting it to /dev/console? echo Hello > /dev/console I'm not sure it works in systemd, though.

Comment: There are all sorts of _basic_ things missing from that question: what version of systemd is running in that VM, whether systemd is indeed the running init system in that VM at all, the status of the service as reported by `systemctl status --full`, what the systemd journal says about the service (`journalctl -u`), and so forth.  Please [Edit] your question and fill in all of these missing parts.

Comment: @GergelyPolonkai: Unfortunately that does not work. (I've tried it.) @JdeBP: At least the version of systemd seems irrelevant to me here as this is a general issue with systemd. Further I'd assume that it is running as init system as the commandline shows `init=lib/systemd/systemd`.

Comment: @Abhishek Did you figure it out. I am trying to do same thing.

Comment: To answer a different question, you can use `journalctl -r -u hello` to see the message in the journal to know that the service ran.